# Turning on and off HP Probook 4530S touchpad 

Tags: 11.10, touchpad

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my HP laptop and among some problems, one of which I'm trying to solve is the touchpad problem. It's working, but how can I turn on/off it?

In SUSE Linux Enterprise Desktop (which was preinstalled) and Windows, the touchpad is enabled/disabled by touching the left upper corner, when small diode is situated. In Ubuntu, I touched that area many times, but nothing happened.

Do anybody know how to solve the problem?

Comment: I also tried to install SLED drivers from HP site using one guide for that (first I converted rpm to deb and then installed them, but that didn't fix the problem, I just have "Touchpad" in unity, when I'm typing "synaptics" but when I clicked - nothing happened.)

Comment: Don't install touchpad-indicator. It will mess up your installation and not add any significant options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is still unsolved.

But if nobody has any thoughts about how to fix that - here is a possible solutions to help those, who can see this topic (guys from russian linux forums helped me).

You can type in your console:

```
syndaemon -t -i 2 -d
```

This means, that your touchpad will be disabled until 2 seconds after your typing will passed.

But there is a way to fix problems with turning off\on your touchpad and with enabling LED works properly... But this way is complicated.
You must download this patches http://abhinandh.com/post/4336662463/getting-the-double-tap-on-the-led-to-disable-touchpad
One patch is for kernel and one for xorg server. Also you have to change function parameters.

Comment: Sadly, the link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking up this same issue for my HP g7. Have you tried the suggestion posted here:

https://askubuntu.com/a/85866/46766

It's not a completely satisfactory solution as it does not re-enable the upper-left corner "diode". But it sounds like it may reduce incidents where brushing the keypad while typing makes a mess of everything.

Comment: Yes, I've tried to do this... Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. But either way thanks for help.

Comment: Yes, I still encounter the problem, too, though perhaps less frequently. Frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I've an HP G62 laptop, and I had the same problem.
I resolved installing touchpad-indicator, which let you disable and enable the touchpad with a shortcut (for example, I use ctrl+alt+p to do that).

To install it you should follow the same instructions:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```

It's available both for 11.10 and for 12.04, now.

Comment: Thanks, i disabled by "synclient TouchPadOff=1". The problem is that touchpad is working not so good as in windows... Even if I touched to him with my wrist it(touchpad) moves my cursor, click him etc... In windows touchpad move cursor and do clicks only when I touch him with fingers.